# Typescript onChange not passing event.Name to dynamically update props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a basic form to work with typescript. I have the follow form and got all of the typings figured out. I can't get the name of the event to dynamically set the state.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component, FormEvent } from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface IState {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

class App extends Component<object, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="txtEmail"
          placeholder="Enter Email"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <input placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.password} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  private handleChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const target = event.target as any;
    console.log(target.name);
    this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value } as IState);
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `console.log(event.name)` is empty so doesn't set my state. I have tried adding and removing `event.persist()` and using `event.target` nothing seems to get the name. Does it have something to do with my typings?

The `target.value` property is correctly passed whenever I type something in the text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the name property to your inputs. e.g.

```
       <input id="txtEmail"
          name="txtEmail"
          placeholder="Enter Email"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that. To update my state dynamically I would have fill it the name field to match my state property. But thanks so much!